# Nested resources not honoring first parameter in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5
I'm working on a simple blog application and I'd like to nest the posts in the blogs as

resources :blogs do
    resources :posts
  end

so the URL should work as /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:post_id
example:
http://wbhauck.com/blogs/1/posts/6

but it also shows the same exact post with blog 2 ...
http://wbhauck.com/blogs/2/posts/6

I've tested and it works as long as the blog_id is a valid blog.  If i put in http://wbhauck.com/blogs/5/posts/6 it throws an error.

The code is available at https://github.com/wbhauck/BlogApp

Either I don't understand how the nested resources are working or it's not working properly.  But I would think it would not work for a post made in a different blog.

I've read the Ruby guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources but it doesn't give an implementation example.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
bill

Answer (score 2):

In your PostsController you should find post among blog's posts

`def set_post
  @post = @blog.posts.find(params[:id])
end`

it will throw exception if post is not in current blog.
Code in routes.rb only responsible for routing url to controller, and not doing anything magical.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.  I was setting the post but directly with
`@post = Post.find(params[:id])`
changing it to
`@post = @blog.posts.find(params[:id])`
fixed it.
Thanks!